# Do Bouillon Cubes/Powder go bad?

Tags: food-safety, storage-method, storage-lifetime, cubes, bouillon

I just found an old jar of Beef Bouillon cubes and although there is no expiration date, I'm a bit skeptical about using them - do they go bad?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Taste them. Bouillon cubes contain enough salt to preserve them from spoilage, but the flavor (which, after all, is why you're using them) may weaken, dull, and change over the years. If you still like their flavor, then go ahead and use them.

Answer (score 13):

IF...

- the jar was tightly sealed and stored in a cool, dry area
- the bouillon cubes don't smell spoiled in any way
- the cubes aren't off-color
- are most likely under 2 years old

then they should be safe. Bouillon can keep for [up to 2 years according to stilltasty.com](http://stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/16596). So, if you think they've been hiding out in the cupboard for over 2 years, I'd toss them.

Comment: JustRight: another great answer!!

Answer (score 1):

Dry, dark, sealed, and cool storage; bouillon should be safe to consume indefinitely. May lose some flavor; but still safe to consume. Lots of salt does preserve quite well.