# Do beef bouillon cubes expire or cause expiration?

Tags: bouillon, cubes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do Bouillon Cubes/Powder go bad?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5508/do-bouillon-cubes-powder-go-bad)

I tossed into the soup the last 2 bouillon cubes in the jar. Then, as I threw it away, I looked at the jar's expiration date: May 1979. Am I going to die?

Comment: 30 years...ouch

Comment: How did you come to have 30 year old bouillon cubes? Time to go through the cupboards and spring clean a little.

Comment: See the answers to that other question... however, I will give you points for a much more entertaining question title!

Comment: Barring unforeseen advances in medical science, yes, you are going to die, but it is not likely to be soon or from 'bad bouillon'.

Comment: My parents have spices in their cabinets older than their marriage and they refuse to let me go through it and 'update'. I am guessing there is stuff in there from 78-79 too. They haven't gotten sick yet >shrugs<

Answer (score 2):

Bouillon cubes can last for quite a while. Thirty years may be pushing that limit, though, as they lose flavor over time. Typically, they are good to use for a year maybe two; that depends on how they were stored, though. If they were in a dry cool place, they should be fine for while. They are loaded with fat and salt which are natural preservatives, anyway. Although dying is unlikely, it is definitely possible to get sick.